# View current number of requests and data transfer on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use Amazon S3 to host static resources for a mobile app. Amazon bills the usage based on both the number of requests made to the resources and the volume of data retrieved. I'm looking for a way to view the current usage.

I'm new to AWS, and overwhelmed with the complexity of the AWS Management Console. There's "AWS Cost Explorer", "AWS Cloud Watch", "Usage Reports", etc. Many things can be installed, configured, downloaded and automated. I don't know where to start looking for a solution.

Is there a simple, graphical chart that just shows me the numbers for the past days?

Comment: Possibly S3 is not the right choice for me - I need a a scalable cloud storage that's easy to maintain and monitor. I'm open for suggestions for better alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For graphs and reporting that you are trying to view, I would use cost explorer in **My Billing Dashboard** for this as it gives you an option to bring up items from a service perspective. Click **services** once the graph comes up and it should give you an in-depth look at what S3 is spending daily. Also, another reporting tool you can look at is the **Month-to-date-spend services** and click bill details. It should give you a break down of what the costs are for S3.

For your comment you left on your post, AWS S3 is one of the best for static content that won't be changed over time as it offers versioning and other great resources for your content. You can even use CloudFront to help distribute those resources as well for a better user experience 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the metrics option available in S3 to get the number of s3 reads made per second.
Steps to view the S3 Bucket

1. Search for S3 bucket in the S3 Bucket Search Box.
2. Once the S3 bucket comes up in the results box, click on the S3 bucket
3. S3 bucket opens up, click on Management tab
4. Once Management tab opens up, click on Metrics button and click on Requests option
5. Its paid option, once its enabled, you could enable number of get request for the per day/week/month.

A detailed document on how to enable could be AWS document page --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html

Once you have the number of requests per month, you could use the aws simple calculator to get the cost -->https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html